# What is this database dump format?

Tags: dump

I have a file which I believed was an Oracle data dump, but Oracle refuses to import it:

```
There is a problem reading from the import files
ORA-39143
"C:\nm\data\THEFILE.dmp" may be an original export dump file
```

The Linux "file" utility says it is DBase 3, but I doubt this, because the records number is not realistic and DBase tools fail to load the file:

```
THEFILE.dmp: DBase 3 data file (1380929624 records)
```

Here is an hex dump of the beginning of the file:

```
0003 4501 5058 524f 3a54 3156 2e30 3230
```

Any idea what database format it could be?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use data pump to import a dump that was created using the old `exp` tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @a_horse_with_no_name says, it's a file created with the [original export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#BABBHCIE) utility, i.e an `exp` command rather than `expdp`. You'll need to import it with the matching [original import](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#i1023560) utility, using the `imp` command.